# How to change a link behavior on desktop and mobile?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have link that should  link to phone number in mobile size like this tel:+989203022438 but in desktop link to my contact page. Is that possible?

Comment: I just asked is it possible or not and thanks to @jared-bledsoe answered me very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, what you need to do is have two elements.
First element (for mobile) and have the text inside of it the telephone number.
Second element (for desktop) with the link to your contact page.
Next, you'll use CSS media queries to set which you should show, something like this:

```
#phoneContact {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #phoneContact {
        display: block;
    }
    #desktopContact {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.